# XPath to select an element based on one of its ancestor's child value

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have the following XML

```
<a>
    <b>
        <TR>
            <FS>AG</FS>
            <TRC>
                <c>
                    <date>1234</date>
                </c>
            </TRC>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <FS>XYZ</FS>
            <TRC>
                <c>
                    <date>5678</date>
                </c>
            </TRC>
        </TR>
    </b>
</a>
```

I'm trying to select all the dates where the FS tag is "AG", So for the given XML it should return 1234

I have been trying the following but it's not working.

```
/a/b/TR[FS = 'AG']/TRC/c/date
```

Comment: Your attempt should work. If it does not, you probably fail to take XML namespaces into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*all the dates where the FS tag is 'AG'"*

```
//date[ancestor::TR[1]/FS = 'AG']
```

or the other way around

```
//TR[FS = 'AG']//date
```

Comment: Thank for the reply Tom. Lets say if FS was the 3rd child of TR, then I would have used the following?  
    //date[ancestor::TR[3]/FS = 'AG']

Comment: No. `ancestor::TR[1]` selects the first (i.e. "closest") `<TR>` on the ancestor axis. It does not matter how many other ancestors are in-between.